# Нет возможности переименовать и удалить файлы в IntelliJ Idea Ultimate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, delete, rename

Не переименовывается и не удаляются файлы в IntelliJ Idea Ultimate. Нажимаю Refactor -> Rename и ничего не происходит. Нажимаю Delete и ничего не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Я пробовал переименовывать файлы разными способами, а также делал invalidate caches, но ничего не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может винда блокирует доступ к папке, попробуй на другом диске создать папку ideaProjects

Comment: Это рабочий ВРМ. Там всего один диск. Если переименовывать не в IDEA, а просто в диске, то переименовывается корректно. Проблема именно в IDEA.

Comment: справа внизу значок замка, должен быть открытым!??

Comment: Проблема решена. Необходимо было выключить плагин JVM Microservices Frameworks/

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Необходимо было отключить плагин JVM Microservices Frameworks.